# what is meaning of EWMA

Tags: algorithm, pandas, prediction, moving-average

I read a paper related to improve mapreduce straggler , the paper use prediction strategy called EWMA to predict the task process speed 
I don't read before about EWMA or any prediction algorithm so if you can help to tell me simple introduction how any algorithm can predict what will happen ?
I searched on Wikipedia and other wepsites but all I get that it uses the previous values to estimate the next values , but it is still a vague idea to me

Comment: Exponential Weighted Moving Average

Comment: @Jeff yes i know the abbreviation but i want to know how it work or when i use it

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/EWMA_chart